# Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_1/bias Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Im developing a sound recognition system using a keras model and then using tensorflow to convert it into a model that can be used on Android. The code is below. X_data and Y_data in the code are numpy binaries and have 2 features: 40 values that represent the MFCCs of the sound, and its label.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import model_selection as ms
from sklearn import preprocessing
import librosa
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf

X_data = np.load('C:\\Users\colew\oneDrive\Desktop\X.npy')
Y_data = np.load('C:\\Users\colew\oneDrive\Desktop\Y.npy')

X=np.array(X_data.tolist())
Y=np.array(Y_data.tolist())
lb=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
yy=np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(Y_data))

aTrain,aTest,bTrain,bTest=ms.train_test_split(X_data,yy,test_size=0.2)

num_labels = yy.shape[1]
filter_size = 2

# build model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(40, )))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
'''
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(40, )))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(40, )))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
'''
model.add(Dense(num_labels, input_shape = (10, )))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
model.fit(aTrain, bTrain, epochs=100, validation_data=(aTest, bTest))

model.save("SDmodel.h5")

# Save tf.keras model in HDF5 format.
keras_file = "keras_model.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)

# Convert to TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Here is an example set of code provided by tensorflow that works and does something similar

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate tf.keras model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy],
              sample_weight_mode='temporal')

x = np.random.random((1, 3))
y = np.random.random((1, 3, 3))
model.train_on_batch(x, y)
model.predict(x)

# Save tf.keras model in HDF5 format.
keras_file = "keras_model.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)

# Convert to TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

That code works perfectly. However, mine ran into some issues after it successfully saved the model and ran into the converting part. Specifically, I run into an issue specifically in the code

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)
```

where I get the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/colew/PycharmProjects/SDModel/SDSoundRecognitionSystem.py", line 77, in <module>
    tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 108, in save_model
    save_weights_to_hdf5_group(model_weights_group, model_layers)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 699, in save_weights_to_hdf5_group
    weight_values = K.batch_get_value(symbolic_weights)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 2777, in batch_get_value
    return get_session().run(tensors)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 930, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1153, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1329, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1349, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_1/bias
     [[node dense_1/bias/read (defined at \Users\colew\PycharmProjects\SDModel\venv\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:402) ]]
```

I'm not really sure where the issue lies, but im assuming since the error has dense_1 in it, it has something to do with the first reference to dense. Any information can be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: run this command in cmd to convert tf.keras https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546666/attempting-to-use-uninitialized-value-dense-1-bias-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

You are useing Sequential model from keras, while the example code uses tf.keras. That might be the problem. I've been having some trouble with that too before..